# Code Blocks при запуске выдаёт ошибку -1073741819. Алгоритм простой замены. С++

Tags: c++, криптография, codeblocks

Мне помогли с написанием программы, на компьютере другого человека программа работает отлично, у меня возвращает постоянно с ошибкой. Не могу разобраться где она находится.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool myfunction (pair<char,double> i, pair<char,double> j) { return (i.second > j.second); }
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ifstream f1("Три мушкетера.txt");
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    char alph[32] = {'я','ю','э','ь','ы','ъ','щ','ш','ч','ц','х','ф','у','т',
    'с','р','п','о','н','м','л','к','й','и','з','ж','е','д','г','в','б','а'};
    vector <pair<char, double>> f(32), m(32);
    char c;
    while(!f1.eof()){
        f1.read((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        if (!isalpha(c)) continue;
        if (isupper(c)) c=tolower(c);
        f[(int(c)) + 32].first = c;
        f[(int(c)) + 32].second ++;
        i++;
    }
    f1.close();
    ifstream f2("Двадцать лет спустя.txt");
    ofstream f3("Закодированный.txt", ios::trunc);
    while(!f2.eof()){
        f2.read((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            f3.write((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
         }
        else {
            if (isupper(c)) c = tolower(c);
            c = alph[int(c) + 32];
            f3.write((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    f2.close();
    f3.close();
    ifstream f4("Закодированный.txt");
    while(!f4.eof()){
        f4.read((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        if (c == 'я') {
            m[31].first = c;
            m[31].second ++;
            k++;
            continue;
        }
        if (!std::isalpha(c)) continue;
        m[(int(c)) + 32].first = c;
        m[(int(c)) + 32].second ++;
        k++;
    }
    f4.close();
    sort (f.begin(), f.end(), myfunction);
    sort (m.begin(), m.end(), myfunction);
    cout << "Буква" << "\t\t\t" << "Шифробуква" << endl;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < f.size(); j++){
        cout << f[j].first << " --- " << f[j].second/i<< "\t\t";
        cout << m[j].first << " --- " << m[j].second/k << endl;
    }
    char key[32] = {'я','ю','ц','ь','ы','ъ','щ','ш','ч','э','х','ф','у','т','с','в','п','о','н','к',
        'л','м','й','и','з','ж','а','д','г','р','б','е'};
    ifstream f5 ("Закодированный.txt");
    ofstream f6 ("Раскодированный.txt", ios::trunc);
    while(!f5.eof()){
        f5.read((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            f6.write((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
         }
        else {
            if (isupper(c)) c = tolower(c);
            c = key[int(c) + 32];
            f6.write((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    f5.close();
    f6.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Первый файл для анализа и шифровки. Второй для дешифровки. Шифровка происходит в файл Закодированный, потом Закодированный файл расшифровывается в Раскодированный. Номер ошибки -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Плохо помогли вам. Удалите и напишите самостоятельно. Я уверен, вы напишете не хуже

Comment: А может Вам просто openssl дернуть, им шифровать и им расшифровывать?

Comment: Тот кто писал, явно пишет цикл ради цикла. Это заметно по `f1...f5`. Если, что-то поменяется будет сложно править алгоритмы... И будете также использовать алгоритм, ради алгоритма =))